# Customize System menubar controls ( windows forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, operating-system

I want to override System menubar controls placed in any desktop window.

I have 2 simple requirements

1. Add one more button (other than already present minimize, maximize and close)
2. Override behavior of Maximize and minimize behavior.

I am not able to get any related material for the above.

P/Invoke is OK for me.

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to add (for instance) a new button for **any window** (not just the window of the application you're building, but all applications such as notepad, explorer...)?

Comment: yes, on all the windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32623/Vista-Aero-ToolStrip-on-Non-Client-Area) and the reference for [DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969512%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Using that, your title bar and buttons would exist in the client area of your app. You could draw whatever you wanted and respond to clicks however you wanted.

You'd have to do things like:

- Figure out the co-ordinates and sizes of the maximise/minimise
  buttons you want to change
- How to add your additional buttons in a way
  consistent with the theme.